# Fastest way to truncate rows in a 2D matrix

Tags: javascript

I have a 2d array with differing lengths

```
array = [
[11,22,33,44],
[66,26,73,94,67,89,22],
[21,55,23,77,43,99,99,3,6]
]
```

When I run a function with n size specified
It must return a array with every row with the n size

if n=3 then the function will output as

```
array = [
[11,22,33],
[66,26,73],
[21,55,23]
]
```

I have tried with

```
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
 newarray.push([array[i][0], array[i][0],array[i][1]])
}

console.log(newarray)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with `slice`?

```js
const array = [
  [11,22,33,44],
  [66,26,73,94,67,89,22],
  [21,55,23,77,43,99,99,3,6]
]

const result = array.map(e => e.slice(0, 3))

console.log(result)
```